# boost semaphore cause segfault

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, ipc

I want poll data form external hardware and send the data by a signal.

My code causes a segfault, when wait on a smaphore in shared memory is called and I can not figure out why.

Below a small example of what I'm doing.
Basically start two boost threads, one writing data in shared memory, the other reading the data.

The main just starts the ThreadHandler ,*sleeps* and stops the ThreadHandler.

header:

```
struct SharedData{
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore sem;
    int data;
    bool newData;
    SharedData():sem(1),newData(false){}
};

class ThreadHandler
{
public:
    ThreadHandler();
    void start();
    void stop();
    boost::thread *m_Thread;
    boost::thread *m_doerThread;
    void doStuff();
    void createSharedMemory();
    void removeSharedMemory();
    SharedData* m_sharedMemory;
};
```

source:

```
void getStuff(int id);


void ThreadHandler::start(){
    createSharedMemory();
    m_doerThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ThreadHandler::doStuff,boost::ref(*this)));
    m_Thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&getStuff,1));
}

void ThreadHandler::stop(){
    m_Thread->interrupt();
    m_doerThread->interrupt();

    m_Thread->join();
    m_doerThread->join();
}

void ThreadHandler::createSharedMemory(){
    removeSharedMemory();
    try{
        boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object sharedObj(boost::interprocess::create_only,SHARED_MEMORY ,boost::interprocess::read_write);
        sharedObj.truncate(sizeof(SharedData));
        boost::interprocess::mapped_region mappedObj(sharedObj,boost::interprocess::read_write);
        SharedData* helper = (SharedData*)mappedObj.get_address();
        m_sharedMemory = new (helper) SharedData;
    }catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &ex){
        std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }catch(std::exception &ex){
        std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}

void ThreadHandler::removeSharedMemory(){
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(SHARED_MEMORY);
}

void ThreadHandler::doStuff(){
    while(1){
        try{
            boost::this_thread::yield();
            m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
            while(!m_sharedMemory->newData){
                m_sharedMemory->sem.post();
                boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
                boost::this_thread::yield();
                m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
            }
            //doStuff
            m_sharedMemory->newData=false;
            m_sharedMemory->sem.post();
        }catch(boost::thread_interrupted &interupt){
            break;
        }catch(std::exception &ex){
            std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
        }catch(...){
            std::cout<<"exception"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void getStuff(int id){
    SharedData* m_sharedMemory;
    try{
        boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object sharedObj(boost::interprocess::open_only,SHARED_MEMORY,boost::interprocess::read_write);
        boost::interprocess::mapped_region mappedObj(sharedObj,boost::interprocess::read_write);
        m_sharedMemory = static_cast<SharedData*>(mappedObj.get_address());
    }catch(std::exception &ex){
        std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    while(1){
        try{
            //get Data from hardware
            int i =1;
            m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
            while(m_sharedMemory->newData){
                m_sharedMemory->sem.post();
                boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
                boost::this_thread::yield();
                m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
            }
            memcpy(&(m_sharedMemory->data),&i,sizeof(int));
            m_sharedMemory->newData=true;
            m_sharedMemory->sem.post();

        }catch(boost::thread_interrupted& ){
            break;
        }catch(std::exception &ex){
            std::cout<<ex.what()<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried boost and std mutexes with the same result.
Do I handle the shared/mapped memory wrong?

Comment: What's with all the pointers, and not freeing object you dynamically allocate? Are you from a Java or C# background?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I must have deleted them also before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    bip::shared_memory_object sharedObj(bip::create_only, SHARED_MEMORY, bip::read_write);
    sharedObj.truncate(sizeof(SharedData));
    bip::mapped_region mappedObj(sharedObj, bip::read_write);
    SharedData *helper = (SharedData *)mappedObj.get_address();
    m_sharedMemory = new (helper) SharedData;
} catch (bip::interprocess_exception &ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Here, you store a pointer (`m_sharedMemory`) to a shared object that goes out of scope as soon as the `try` block exits. Boom!

Same problem in the producer:

```
SharedData *m_sharedMemory;
try {
    bip::shared_memory_object sharedObj(bip::open_only, SHARED_MEMORY, bip::read_write);
    bip::mapped_region mappedObj(sharedObj, bip::read_write);
    m_sharedMemory = static_cast<SharedData *>(mappedObj.get_address());
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

C++ has deterministic storage lifetimes, and no garbage collection. As the commentor hinted, just sprinkling `new` left and right doesn't you any good. In fact, it makes your life a lot worse because now you have to worry about cleanup and exception safety.

Instead, use automatic storage durations (stack, locals, members) but make sure the lifetime of your objects suffices for all code using it.

Here's a fixed demo that seems to do what you want:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/813cb99c6b5ffaad)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <fstream>

#define SHARED_MEMORY "29939FC9-D56B-43A0-AED3-239B8DD4182B"

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

struct SharedData {
    bip::interprocess_semaphore sem;
    int data;
    bool newData;
    SharedData() : sem(1), newData(false) {}
};

struct ThreadHandler {
    ThreadHandler() { }
    void start();
    void stop();
    boost::thread m_producer;
    boost::thread m_consumer;
    void consumer_func();

    void createSharedMemory();
    void removeSharedMemory();

    bip::shared_memory_object m_sharedObj;
    bip::mapped_region m_mappedObj;
    SharedData *m_sharedMemory = nullptr;

    ~ThreadHandler() {
        stop(); 
    }
};

void producer_func(int);

void ThreadHandler::start() {
    createSharedMemory();
    m_consumer = boost::thread(&ThreadHandler::consumer_func, this);
    m_producer = boost::thread(&producer_func, 1);
}

void ThreadHandler::stop() {
    m_producer.interrupt();
    m_consumer.interrupt();

    m_producer.join();
    m_consumer.join();
}

void ThreadHandler::createSharedMemory() {
    removeSharedMemory();
    try { 
        m_sharedObj    = bip::shared_memory_object(bip::create_only, SHARED_MEMORY, bip::read_write);
        m_sharedObj.truncate(sizeof(SharedData));
        m_mappedObj    = bip::mapped_region(m_sharedObj, bip::read_write);
        m_sharedMemory = new (m_mappedObj.get_address()) SharedData;
    } catch (bip::interprocess_exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void ThreadHandler::removeSharedMemory() {
    try {
        m_sharedMemory = nullptr;
        bip::shared_memory_object::remove(SHARED_MEMORY);
    } catch(...) {}
}

void ThreadHandler::consumer_func() {
    while (1) {
        try {
            boost::this_thread::yield();
            m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
            while (!m_sharedMemory->newData) {
                m_sharedMemory->sem.post();
                boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
                boost::this_thread::yield();
                m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
            }
            // doStuff
            std::cout << "." << std::flush;
            m_sharedMemory->newData = false;
            m_sharedMemory->sem.post();
        } catch (boost::thread_interrupted &interupt) {
            break;
        } catch (std::exception &ex) {
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "exception" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void producer_func(int) {
    try {
        bip::shared_memory_object sharedObj(bip::open_only, SHARED_MEMORY, bip::read_write);
        bip::mapped_region mappedObj(sharedObj, bip::read_write);
        auto m_sharedMemory = static_cast<SharedData *>(mappedObj.get_address());

        while (1) {
            try {
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(50));
                // get Data from hardware
                int i = 1;
                m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
                while (m_sharedMemory->newData) {
                    m_sharedMemory->sem.post();
                    boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
                    boost::this_thread::yield();
                    m_sharedMemory->sem.wait();
                }
                memcpy(&(m_sharedMemory->data), &i, sizeof(int));
                m_sharedMemory->newData = true;
                m_sharedMemory->sem.post();

            } catch (boost::thread_interrupted &) {
                break;
            } catch (std::exception &ex) {
                std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    ThreadHandler th;
    th.start();
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
}
```

Comment: Added a cleaned up example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/813cb99c6b5ffaad (Coliru doesn't support shared memory, neither [does Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2Sv7GCrs64yIioE2))

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the (now) strange idea of the thread keeping the mapped memory in scope - but the thread has not to bee a boost thread. so I messed it up.

Comment: @user7236868 no problem at all; just drop the interruption points: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0863e2e3aed1773e

Comment: in your example with std::thread the threads do not finish. I have added a boolean to SharedData for breaking the loops in my code

Comment: Like I said. If you need/want the interruption point, use Boost Thread. Obviously, interruption points won't work inter-process anyways.